How to draw a round corner non orthogonal line in TikZ LaTeX?
I want to draw a round corner non-orthogonal line in TikZ LaTeX a depicted here! Any suggestions?


Welcome. // Suggestions: post your code, read the pgfmanual, search here for \draw.

Thanks, I tried to draw this line in two segments, but I do not get rounded corners. I also looked on the web, but what I found is that you can only draw orthogonal rounded corner lines! @MS-SPO

Please show, don’t tell, like in any good novel.

Read this chapter of the online TikZ manual. This is actually quite easy to do with the option rounded corners.

\draw[rounded corners=10pt,line width=3pt] (0,0)--(3,-5)--(3,-8);


For a prefect answer the posted code also would compile ;-)

Obviously I have the compilable code! I make this express. So Nick Cooper have to complete the code to see if my answer is correct.

Thanks, this is what was looking for! @RaffaeleSantoro
